# How do i pass list as a input parameter to the TBV function?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-5, sql-function

I have a TBV function and want to pass my function list type parameter like this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Functiont]
(
 @listType (what  type i could use here ??)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(   
SELECT d.*, b.Name AS Name, ps.Name AS PaymentSystemName, c.UserName AS UserName, c.FirstName AS ClientFirstName, c.LastName AS LastName, c.Number AS DocumentNumber, c.Id
FROM Document AS d
JOIN System AS ps ON d.SystemId = ps.Id
JOIN Client AS c ON c.Id = d.ClientId
LEFT JOIN Shop AS b ON b.Id = d.ShopId
WHERE d.OperationTypeId IN (2, 4, 5) AND c.Type = 1
)
```

And i want to use this @listType in my function,particularly to check is that list contain any value or not and do something with that value.I am calling this function through Entity Framework 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In old days we used to pass comma separated string and split it into a table. Now SQL Server supports User-Defined table type, which can be used in your scenario.

To create a new User Defined table type

```
 CREATE TYPE CustomList AS TABLE 
 ( 
   ListItem VARCHAR(50)
 )
 GO
```

How to Declare

```
DECLARE @MyList CustomList
```

How to use

```
INSERT INTO @MyList
SELECT '1'
GO
INSERT INTO @MyList
SELECT '2'
```

In your case you can your list type as following.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Functiont]
(
 @listType MYLIST
)
....
....
```

To know more about this visit [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)

To know how to use table type in entity framework you can check [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1033512/Executing-Stored-Procedure-with-User-Defined-Table)

Comment: Do i need some specific way to pass  list as a input parameter to the function or i could do that as simple as another types(strings,ints etc) ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with 1 sample link. This will help.

Comment: Just now saw it thanks.by the way that link  show how to use in sp's. Or it does not matter function or sp?The behavior same for boths?

Comment: Check this for table valued function in Entity Framework blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support.aspx